# Ansible package installation as meta dependency or task

Tags: ansible, architecture, ansible-role

This is a design / architecture question to resolve my messed-up brain :)

With ansible I want to install a package on my systems via role.

There are two ways in this discussion:

1. Specify the package(s) as role dependency in `meta/main.yml`

   ```
   ---
   dependencies:
     - role: 'custom-apt-wrapper'
       pkg_name: 'my-awesome-package'
   ```
2. Specify the package(s) as tasks in `tasks/main.yml`

   ```
   ---
   - name: Install package 'my-awesome-package'
     apt:
       name: my-awsome-package
       state: present
   ```

Both of these options are functional but the question is:

- Which of these options is the correct way to go by the ansible design?
- Is there a better solution?
- Are there any hidden problems to run into when moving on with one of these?

**What I understand is:**

If I like to manage something my role is not responsible for, I should and would include it as dependency. If not, I would install the package with a task.

**Let's make an example:**

*A Python package should be present on the system but is only available via pip.*

1. Solution with Dependency:

   - Install the pip package via the pip-wrapper role within the `meta/main.yml` dependencies array.
2. Solution with Tasks:

   - My role would have a dependency to the pip role to assure pip is present on the system.
   - Then I would manage (install) the pip package in the `tasks/main.yml`.

For me the 2. solution is much more understandable and flexible. Just think about installation package sets by condition or include other task files by condition. In the meta dependencies array, it would be one big array of things.

If anyone has experience with this, I really like to hear what you think about this! Thanks!

Comment: You can also consider not managing any dependency automatically and simply fail your role with a meaningful message asking the user to install the needed package. This is usefull when there are several ways / roles / solutions to install something and you don't want to force the user to go your route. Meanwhile, there is no single good answer to the above and your will probably get as many as there are different situations and opinions, which makes your question [off-topic](/help/on-topic) IMHO.

Comment: Where are you seeing it is valid to have 'pkg_name' under dependencies?

Comment: pkg_name is a variable in the custom apt wrapper role.

Comment: Hrm, most of the docs have you putting any variables for the rule under a 'vars' section. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies

Comment: Oh thanks for that!